# Angular's 2 templateURL functionality on another javascript library

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-framework

I am about the start working on a project which I want to avoid using Angular 2 as it's still not out there and this project will be finished way before Angular2 will be released.

One thing I really like in Angular 2 is it's: templateURL , where you can import html templates at runtime very easily and works great.

After googling I've found Webpack or Browserify but not sure how good they are for this specific functionality I'm looking for.

Are their any other javascript libraries or released frameworks that have this same functionality, if so, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself with those simple steps:

1. Get the html file as string in your code (using http get on the file).
2. Injecting the result into the DOM. (using `innerHTML` or some other method)

No framework needed.